# KDTree is Returning Points Outside of Radius

Tags: python, scipy, geolocation, geospatial, latitude-longitude

I have an array of lat long coordinates and I am trying to use a KDTree and scipy's `query_ball_point` to return all data points within a 1 mile radius of a designated latitude and longitude.

The problem is that `query_ball_point` is returning points that are outside of the specified 1 mile radius.  Here's my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import scipy as sp
import geocoder
import pysal as psl


search_list = df['coordinates'].tolist()
tree = psl.cg.KDTree(search_list, distance_metric='Arc', radius=psl.cg.RADIUS_EARTH_MILES)
latlong = (39.698840000000004, -104.975916)
index = tree.query_ball_point(latlong,r=1)
```

The result is an array of coordinates like the following:

```
+---------------------------------------+
|              coordinates              |
+---------------------------------------+
| (39.676973877551, -104.966231826172)  |
| (39.6777407534644, -104.988982458831) |
| ...                                   |
+---------------------------------------+
```

When I try to use the haversine formula to validate these results, I see the first coordinate is 1.6  miles way

```
from haversine import haversine
haversine((39.676973877551, -104.966231826172),
         (39.698840000000004, -104.975916),miles=True)

1.5961362762187963
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pysal doesn't use the haversine function to calculate distance for the query_ball_point method.  It uses the pysal.cg.sphere.arcdist function, which is different.

```
import pysal
from pysal.cg.kdtree import KDTree    

locations = [(40.702566, -73.816859),
         (40.70546, -73.810708),
         (40.709179, -73.820574),
         (40.700486, -73.807969),
         (40.694624, -73.820593),
         (40.695132, -73.820841),
         (40.694095, -73.821334),
         (40.694165, -73.822368),
         (40.695077, -73.822817),
         (40.6747769261, -73.8092618174)] 
tree = KDTree(locations, distance_metric='Arc', radius=pysal.cg.RADIUS_EARTH_MILES)
current_point = (40.709523, -73.802472)
# get all points within X miles of 'current_point'
indices = tree.query_ball_point(current_point, 1)
for i in indices:
    print(locations[i])
```

There are 3 points within 1 mile

```
(40.70546, -73.810708)
(40.700486, -73.807969)
(40.6747769261, -73.8092618174)
```

Not all these points are within 1 mile according to haversine formula:

```
from haversine import haversine
for i in indices:
    print(haversine(current_points, locations[i], miles = True))

0.5146716729994124
0.6875825817591269
2.4269297885659022
```

But they are within 1 mile according to pysal's arcdist formula using radius of 3958.756 miles:

```
from pysal.cg.sphere import arcdist
for i in indices:
    print(arcdist(current_points, locations[i], 3958.756))

0.5744128196875283
0.4178272122350164
0.8175408580090955
```

Answer (score 0):

PySAL expects the input to be (**longitude, latitude**) (i.e. x,y) while the haversine python package expects (**latitude, longitude**).  Otherwise arcdist and haversine should return near identical results.

```
from libpysal.cg.sphere import arcdist, RADIUS_EARTH_MILES
from haversine import haversine

locations = [(40.702566, -73.816859),
         (40.70546, -73.810708),
         (40.709179, -73.820574),
         (40.700486, -73.807969),
         (40.694624, -73.820593),
         (40.695132, -73.820841),
         (40.694095, -73.821334),
         (40.694165, -73.822368),
         (40.695077, -73.822817),
         (40.6747769261, -73.8092618174)] 
current_point = (40.709523, -73.802472)

H = [haversine(current_point, loc, unit='mi') for loc in locations]
print(', '.join(["%0.5f"%dist for dist in H]))
A = [arcdist(current_point[::-1], loc[::-1], radius=RADIUS_EARTH_MILES) for loc in locations]
print(', '.join(["%0.5f"%dist for dist in A]))
print(', '.join(['%0.8f'%(h-a) for h,a in zip(H,A)]))
```

Out:

```
0.89381, 0.51467, 0.94839, 0.68758, 1.40024, 1.38364, 1.45343, 1.48732, 1.46011, 2.42693
0.89381, 0.51467, 0.94838, 0.68758, 1.40024, 1.38364, 1.45343, 1.48732, 1.46011, 2.42693
0.00000123, 0.00000071, 0.00000131, 0.00000095, 0.00000193, 0.00000191, 0.00000201, 0.00000205, 0.00000202, 0.00000335
```